configuring env-vars for R-Studio Server users using SystemD
I am an admin for a RHEL 8 linux server running r-studio server (the free version.) By default, many R packages that have parallelization (interfacing with Open MP) assume they have all the cores on the system at their disposal. As a consequence, users running r packages like xgboost are causing server crashes at my organization. I've been able to set a default maximum for number of cores used by a session to 4 for R scripts running outside the rstudio ide by setting OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 in a profile.d script, but I'm having trouble figuring out where I can set OMP_NUM_THREADS in a way that rstudio server users will be affected. The desired behavior is for r-studio server sessions to be limited to below 400% CPU as measured by top by default, but I am okay if users can override this.
I've tried adding an override.conf file for rstudio-server's systemD unit file using sudo systemctl edit rstudio-server to add the following text and restarting the service with no success (r-studio sessions still use the maximum number of cores available.)
[Service]
Environment="OMP_NUM_THREADS=4"

I've also tried setting OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 in {R_HOME}/etc/Renviron.site, the environment variable shows up in the session but has no effect on the underlying behavior.
This is a script that would "run R off the rails":
library(xgboost) #for fitting the xgboost model
library(caret) #for general data preparation and model fitting

#load the data (duplicate a few times to simulate bigger dataset)
data = rbind(MASS::Boston)
for(i in 1:250){
  data = rbind(data, MASS::Boston)
}
data = rbind(data, data)
data = rbind(data, data)
data = rbind(data, data)

#make this example reproducible
set.seed(0)

#split into training (80%) and testing set (20%)
parts = createDataPartition(data$medv, p = .8, list = F)
train = data[parts, ]
test = data[-parts, ]

#define predictor and response variables in training set
train_x = data.matrix(train[, -13])
train_y = train[,13]

#define predictor and response variables in testing set
test_x = data.matrix(test[, -13])
test_y = test[, 13]

#fit XGBoost model to training set
xgb_train = xgb.DMatrix(data = train_x, label = train_y)
xgb_test = xgb.DMatrix(data = test_x, label = test_y)

#define watchlist
watchlist = list(train=xgb_train, test=xgb_test)

#fit XGBoost model and display training and testing data at each round
model = xgb.train(data = xgb_train, max.depth = 3, watchlist=watchlist, nrounds = 70)

#define final model
final = xgboost(data = xgb_train, max.depth = 3, nrounds = 56, verbose = 0)

Running this script in a bash session after running export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 simulates the desired behavior (this has the same effect as my profile.d scripts, limiting CPU to below 400%), but I want this to happen for all r-studio server users.
Any advice is greatly appreciated!

OMP_NUM_THREADS only limits the number of threads used for a parallel region. It does not limit the total number of threads that can be spawned from an OpenMP process and certainly not the number of threads spawned from the sum of OpenMP processes. I think, systemd might spawn multiple server processes, if enough request come in? Furthermore, the server process might spawn multiple threads to handle the requests, each of them is allowed to spawn it's own parallel region with 4 threads in your configuration. You might want to limit to 1 thread for the server. Or use OMP_THREAD_LIMIT=10?

Thanks for the suggestion. I'm okay with users being able to use more than 4 cores, I'm just trying to set a default value that is more reasonable than "the amount of cores available". In practice, if I set OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 or OMP_THREAD_LIMIT=4 in a bash session before running my script above and they both have the effect of limiting CPU to less than 400%. What I need to know is where do I set either of these so they affect R Studio Server users system wide?

I just received a working solution to this question in another forum! Someone helpfully pointed me to the following github issue which provides a method that worked for me: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/10641#issuecomment-1116764936

The full solution: for RStudio Server Sessions, you need to move /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rsession to a new location (rsession.real for instance) and replace it with a shell script containing:
#!/bin/sh
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4
exec /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rsession.real "$@"
